# How to configure selenium webdriver script and powershell script to run once in a week

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, taskscheduler

I have one selenium webdriver script and another powershell script.
I want to configure both scripts to run on each thursday at 6 pm. How to achieve that.

Comment: Review Windows Task Scheduler and then update your question with your attempts at making it work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Windows Scheduled task to run a PowerShell script.

Here is the step by step guide on how to do that.

[Use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script/)

Then just schedule the script according to your timelines.

If you want to configure the scheduled task also using PS, then here is my blog to help you out on that.

[PS Scheduled Task Script](https://onejourneymultipletechnologies.blogspot.in/2016/10/scheduled-task-in-powershell.html)

Alternative,

Creation of Task Scheduler Script using cmdlets:

[powershell create scheduled-tasks](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-build-scheduled-tasks,2-832.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Selenium (don't know what that is), but PowerShell scripts can be scheduled using the regular Windows Task Scheduler.

Scheduled tasks can be manually created using the Windows Task Scheduler (taskschd.msc), or via the command-line using schtasks.exe, e.g.:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /sc weekly /d THU /st 18:00 /tn MyPowerShellJob /tr "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file d:\MyScript.ps1 \"hello world\" foo" /ru JohnDoe /rp
```